# Merge Multiple SQL Table Columns into One

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as such (with thousand of rows):

| ogr_fid (PK, int, not null) | 90 (varchar(157), null) | 80 (varchar(157), null) | 70 (varchar(157), null) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some_text | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | other_text |
| 3 | NULL | more_text | NULL |
| 4 | even_more_text | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I would like to merge the table to read as follows;

| ogr_fid (PK, int, not null) | m_agl (int, null) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 |
| 2 | 70 |
| 3 | 80 |
| 4 | 90 |
| 5 | NULL |

As you can see I will use the text as simply a `IS NOT NULL` sort of test. The merged column will be populated with the name of the `IS NOT NULL` column.

I have been trying to understand `IIF` and `CASE` but it is far beyond my current level of understanding without a working example to learn from.

My latest attempt:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_table] ADD [m_agl] AS SELECT 
   CASE WHEN 90 IS NOT NULL THEN '90'
   CASE WHEN 80 IS NOT NULL THEN '80'
   CASE WHEN 70 IS NOT NULL THEN '70'
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_table] DROP COLUMN (90, 80, 70)
GO
```

Many thanks.

Comment: "I have been trying to understand IIF and CASE" - the official docs have plenty of clear, easy to follow examples.

Comment: First of all, you'll need to escape the column names since they're not identifiers on their own -- so `[90], [80], [70]` -- otherwise they're just interpreted as integer constants. Second, you can't add a computed column based on these columns, then drop the columns -- you'll need a *new* column that starts off empty and is then filled using `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Note, a Column name cannot be naked integer.

### Solution using `IIF`

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_table] ADD [column_merged];
GO

SELECT ogr_fid, IIF(column_1 IS NOT NULL, column_1, IIF(column_2 IS NOT NULL, column_2, IIF(column_3 IS NOT NULL, column_3, NULL)))
FROM dbo.my_table;
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_table] DROP COLUMN (column_1, column_2, column_3);
GO
```

Learn more about `CASE` at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) 
Learn more about `IIF` at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: _Column name cannot be naked integer._ That is not correct. It **is highly discouraged** since it violates the rules for regular identifiers but it can be and will require delimiters if it is.

Comment: I *suspect* @Smor, that by "naked" the user means "not delimit identified"  (though I didn't want to make that assumption when I edited the post), as they do reference several delimit identified columns in their SQL where the name only contains numerical characters.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need to use [`is null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (with `not`) rather than `<> NULL`? How does your code arrive at the values `'70'`, `'80'` and `'90'` for the new column?

Comment: Oh just noticed the syntax issue, Edited and resolved!
`'70'`, `'80'` and `'90'` where to make the answer easy to understand as per question..   Anyway Thanks @HABO